# Recommendation for new python user

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, pycharm, peewee

I'm new on the programming world using python, so i have some questions for desktop aplications development.
1. Im currently using pycharm as my idle, can i use it for my purpose?
2. Can i use peewee as my ORM and Tkinter for my GUI? or should i just use Tkinter?(Recommendations are welcome)
3. I'm planning to use Sqlite3 as my database, should i keep this idea?

My further plan is to make an application to store the networks equipments in an enterprise, like desktops, laptops, switches, etc.
And also get some reports like to wich user belongs a desktop or laptop, wich kind of license does the equip has, a bitacore to store all what happens to an equip, etc.

I'm very new on this world and have been reading, practicing and taking courses for 3 month by now to understand concepts, learn about programming, etc.

Tahnks for the tips.

Comment: IMO: 1) Yes 2) Just tkinter for now 3) Definitely. Good luck!

Comment: I recomment reading [ask] - you question is offtopic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you know Tkinter then stick with it, otherwise consider a higher level framework like PyGUI, PySimpleGUI or QT (Arguably not that simple, but plays nicely with PyInstaller). You will definitely be able to keep using SQLite3, as there is an existing binding in python 2&3.

If you plan to deploy this app, then you need to consider if speed is going to be a problem. Python is great but fundamentally quite slow. You can use things like Cython or PyPy to speed it up, but this can get complicated when you look at using a packager such as py2exe or PyInstaller for distribution.

best of luck.